# Convert the contents of directory and its subdirectories to JSON

Tags: json, perl, directory, find, text-processing

I have the following perl script from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90115/convert-output-of-tree-command-to-json-format) stack exchange question that converts the content of a directory into JSON.

```
use File::Find; 
use JSON; 
use strict; 
use warnings; 

my $dirs={}; 
my $encoder = JSON->new->ascii->pretty; 
find({wanted => \&process_dir, no_chdir => 1 }, "."); 

print $encoder->encode($dirs); 
sub process_dir { 
    return if !-d $File::Find::name; 
    my $ref=\%$dirs; 

    for(split(/\//, $File::Find::name)) { 
        $ref->{$_} = {} 
        if(!exists $ref->{$_}); 
        $ref = $ref->{$_}; 
  } 
}
```

I'm running the script using Termux on Android 6.0.

Consider the following directory:

```
.
 |--server .
 |         | - File 1.tmp
 |         | - File 2.sql
 |         | - File 3.sql
 |-- js .
 |         | - File 1.js
 |         | - File 2.js
 |         | - File 3.js
 | -css .
 |         | - File 1.js
 |         | - File 2.js
 |         | - File 3.js
 | -assets .
 |         | - Font-awesome 
 |         |        .
 |         |        | - webfont.
 |         |        |          | - File 2.woff
 |         |        |          | - File 2.woff
 |         |        |          | - File 3.woff
 |         |        | - css .
 |         |        |       | - File 2.css
 |         |        |       | - File 2.css
 |         |        |       | - File 3.css
 |         | - Fonts
 |         |        | - ps  .
 |         |        |       | - File 2.woff
 |         |        |       | - File 2.css
 |         |        |       | - File 3.txt
 |         | - images 
 |         |        | - File 1.png
 |         |        | - File 2.png
 |         |        |   - File 3.svg
```

The script returns the following if I execute it in the above directory:

```
{
"." : {
      "server" : {},                               
      "js" : {},
      "css" : {},
      "assets" : {
         "fonts" : {                                       
            "ps":{}
         },
         "images" : {},
         "font-awesome" : {
            "css" :{},                                     
            "webfonts" : {}
         }
      }                                 
     }                                            
    }
```

I'm trying to edit the script to additionally include the files in each subdirectory as a Js array (if it's possible using perl + JSON Module, or, just Perl)

**Eg** [Edit]

```
{
"." : {
      "server" : {"Files": ["File1", "File2", "File n"]},
      /* Or just "server" : ["File1", "File2", "File n"], ... */
      "js" : {"Files": ["File1", "File2", "File n"]},                                
      "assets" : {
         "fonts" : {                                       
             "ps":{"Files": ["File1", "File2", "File n"]}
          },
         "images" : {"Files": ["File1", "File2", "File n"]},
         "font-awesome" : {
         "css" : {"Files": ["File1", "File2", "File n"]}                    
         "webfonts" : {"Files": ["File1", "File2", "File n"]}
     }
  }     
 }                                            
}
```

Is this achievable? If so, how should I go about it? I'm relatively new to perl and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this.

Comment: I'm afraid, you have over-simplified your problem space and given an incomplete example of your desired output format. You have now an output format example that only has 1 level of directory depth ( server and assets ) whereas the directory/file structure clearly has multiple levels. You do not just have 'File's, but also directories. Please update the desired output such that you show files and directories, please rethink the JSON structure you really desire ... and the answer to "if it's possible using..." or "is it achievable?" is YES

Comment: Note that I've used /* ... */ to indicate the rest fo the subdirectories (for simplicity) but, yes, I'd like to iterate through every subfolder and have the output as shown in the server/assets folder. I'll edit the question for clarity purposes.

Comment: Can you show the contents of the directory for which you show the JSON sample?  (Or just clarify: are those keys filenames? Or directories?  Or either/both? Are the nested dictionaries directory hierachies?) By "_converts the content of a directory into JSON_" do you mean to build the JSON with filenames?

Comment: @zdim - I have a folder with subfolders and each subfolder has different levels of subdirectories, each with it's own different number of files. I'd like to convert the folder/subfolders structure into a nested JSON object with directory names as object names and the files names as the values (in form of arrays). I've edited question to show the desired output.

Comment: What's the difference between "images" and "css" in your example?

Comment: @clamp I've edited the question to include a directory structure

Comment: Your structure does not have directories with both, files and directories in it.

Comment: @clamp - Yes, The current structure has all the files enclosed in their own subfolder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave it a try and decided to move the file names to an entry with the special key `__files__`. This will break if you have a directory named like that.

```
use File::Find; 
use JSON; 
use strict; 
use warnings;
use 5.12.0;
use Data::Dumper;
my $dirs={}; 
my $encoder = JSON->new->ascii->pretty; 
find({wanted => \&process_dir, no_chdir => 1 }, "."); 
print $encoder->encode($dirs); 
sub process_dir { 
    my $full_name = $File::Find::name;
    my $ref=$dirs; 
    if (-d $full_name ) {
        for (split(/\//, $full_name)) {  # only directories
            $ref->{$_} ||= {};  # create the next level if it does not exist
            $ref = $ref->{$_};  # move to the next level         
        }
    } else {
        for (split(/\//, $full_name)){  # n directories and 1 filename
            if (exists $ref->{$_}) {    # it's a directory
                $ref = $ref->{$_}
            } else {
                push @{$ref->{__files__}}, $_;  # it's a filename
                # $ref->{$_} = '_is_file_';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great!! I noticed the list of files for each directory is added to a JSON property called `__files__` e.g: `"css" : { "__files__" : ["stylesheet.main.css", "jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"]}`. Is it possible to have the array containing filenames directly under it's parent? Eg. `"css" : ["stylesheet.main.css", "jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"]`

Comment: `{[string]}` is not valid in JSON. `[filename,...]` will fail if you have files and directories. How about `{filename : _is_file_}` or something like that?

Comment: I found a way to modify the obtained JSON obj (+ a JS script) to achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Following piece of code puts directory structure into hash and then converts it into JSON format

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my $data;

my $dir = shift // '.';   # // correct website highlighting

$data->{$dir} = traverse($dir);

my $encoder = JSON->new->ascii->pretty; 

print $encoder->encode($data); 

sub traverse {
    my $dir = shift;

    my($dh,$data);

    $data->{'files'} = ();

    opendir($dh, $dir)
        or die "Could not open $dir";

    while( my $name = readdir($dh) ) {
        next if $name eq '.' or $name eq '..';

        my $path = "$dir/$name";

        $data->{$name} = traverse($path) if -d $path;
        push @{$data->{'files'}}, $name  if -f $path;
    }

    closedir $dh;

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other variation of the code: *files are array elements*, *directories* are *hash* with *key directory name* and *content as array*, then converted to JSON format

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my $data;

my $dir = shift // '.';    # // correct website highlighting

$data->{$dir} = traverse($dir, $dir);

my $encoder = JSON->new->ascii->pretty; 

print $encoder->encode($data); 


sub traverse {
    my $dir  = shift;
    my $name = shift;

    my($dh,@data,%ret);

    opendir($dh, $dir)
        or die "Could not open $dir";


    while( my $name = readdir($dh) ) {
        next if $name eq '.' or $name eq '..';

        my $path = "$dir/$name";

        push @data, traverse($path,$name) if -d $path;
        push @data, $name                 if -f $path;
    }

    closedir $dh;

    return ( $name => \@data );
}
```